# How should I choose the name of my past degree in application when the options do not not exactly match my degree?

Tags: phd, application, degree, terminology

I am applying for PhD for a certain university (Canadian), and in the form there is a question about the academic background. In the options I see things like Bachelor of engineering, bachelor of engineering with honours, bachelor's degree general, bachelor's degree 4 year, and bachelor of science. There are similar options for the Master's degree: Master of engineering, Master's degree, and master's of science.

I completed my undergraduate study in 4 years and my degree is "Bachelor of science in engineering".There was a project in the final year. I am doing a "Master's of science in engineering". This is thesis based degree.

Which of the above options should I choose? In my country we only have Bachelor of science and Master's of science so I don't know what these things mean.

Comment: I am applying to phd programs in the US, and, after contacting the schools, the responses are: Choose the closest one. Lest there be any unnecessary error, just contact the school! I believe the staff member will reply in a timely fashion with etiquette.

Comment: In regards to your question about what a `Master of Engineering` is, [this wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEng) covers it. For example, an MEng Degree from the United Kingdom would be considered an undergraduate degree as it is provided in lieu of a Bachelor's and has the same study length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "I see things like," I assume you mean "the options are," i.e., the list of options you have given is exhaustive. I shall also assume that you are an engineering student, with a degree at "Bachelor of science" level and you are currently studying at "Master's of science" level. The question about academic background is looking for your highest qualification, so I would list "master's of science."

You could call the university to confirm!

EDIT. I do not agree with [compass's](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/22013/compass) remark that a UK MEng degree is provided in lieu of a Bachelor's and has the same study length: UK BEng degrees are typically three years, whereas UK MEng degrees are typically four years. It is possible that [compass](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/22013/compass) is attempting to compare Bachelor's degrees between different countries.